# Subscripted assginment dimenstion mismatch - Error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

i have an array of multiple rows and 5 columns(fixed) , i need to save values dynamically(in loop)
I did this thing.

```
for i from 1 to n do
    A(i,:)=[var1 var2 var3 var4 var5]
end_for
```

But it gives error.
Anyone who knows the solution, Please help me..
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code example is not Matlab.

What the error you got means is that the size of `A(counter,:)` (the variable into which you try to assign new values) does not match the size of `[var1 var2 var3 var4 var5]`.

Use debug mode, put a breakpoint at the problematic line and check what is `size( A(counter,:) )` and what is `size([var1 var2 var3 var4 var5])` then fix your code so that these two sizes would actually match.

Good luck!

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: If I could, I'd add an extra +1 for the remark on `i`, my fellow Don Quixote.